# Input group in Uikit

Tags: html, css, uikit, getuikit

I am trying to make input group using [uikit](http://getuikit.com/index.html). I would like to have input box and button side by side like [bootstrap input-group class](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic). Can you please tell me how and what is the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, the uikit framework does not provide such a built-in input-group.

However, with a little css you can accomplish the same thing.

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wannieboy/okwdsjxd/ you find that i created a normal uikit `<form class="uk-form">` with an input & button that look like the bootstrap inputgroup.

I've added a wrapper `<div>` with a `test` class + i added the `myborder` class to the `button` element. 
This was just a quick fiddle and works for **only** this case.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks! Could also be done with uk-flex I suppose.